# Do we need an article before 'wife' in this sentence?

Tags: articles

Here's a sentence from a [textbook](https://issuu.com/macmillaneducation/docs/gateway_b1_sb_u1):

> You can use the word *partner* to describe either a husband or wife or the person that someone lives with.

Why is there no article before the word 'wife'? Is it correct English grammar?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks you for your question. The indefinite article **a** here is the determiner for both _husband_ and _wife._ Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Whenever possible, you should include a link to the book you are quoting.

Comment: Thank you. It's this book: [link](http://www.macmillanenglish.com/products/gateway-b1-student-book/) Do I understand correctly that **husband or wife** here is a noun phrase and **or** in this noun phrase is not a part of **either-or** structure?

Comment: Excellent! Now use the [edit] link to add the source to your question. This will be good practice for the next time you ask a question here.

Comment: Done! Link added.

Comment: I wasn't clear. We don't need a link to a place where we can buy the book; we need a link to the _actual text quoted_ in the question, if it's available. For instance: https://issuu.com/macmillaneducation/docs/gateway_b1_sb_u1

Comment: **Or** is part of the either-or structure here. The indefinite article **a** is the determiner for both _husband_ and _wife._

Comment: Is it ellipsis then? [page 175](http://ielts-house.net/Ebook/Vocabulary/Practical%20English%20usage.pdf) As far as I know, we need to use an article before each singular countable noun or noun phrase in a sentence.

Comment: It's not an ellipsis. When we use a conjunction like **or** or **and**, we can use one instance of the article as the determiner for all of the nouns in the phrase. See [**this link**](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/270659/192771).

Answer (score 2):

> You can use the word partner to describe either a husband or wife or
>   the person that someone lives with.

This is known as parallel structure. The first paragraph at this first site explains it best. In a parallel construction repeat an article (a, an, the), a preposition, or pronoun whenever necessary to make the meaning clear. The meaning of "a husband or (a) wife" is clearly understood.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/

At this next site, scroll down to all the ***NOTES*** about what you can omit in a parallel construction

http://english.tutorvista.com/grammar/parallel-structure.html

http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-parallelism.html